# How can I pass a char array to a constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm trying to manipulate a string at compile-time.
To do that, I'm creating a wrapper class for the string.

This is my code:

```cpp
template <size_t nSize>
class strwrapper_t
{
private:
    char m_sInput[nSize] = {}; // init as empty

public:
    constexpr strwrapper_t(const char sInput[nSize])
    { }
};

class strwrapper
{
public:
    template <size_t nSize>
    constexpr static auto create(const char(&sInput)[nSize]) -> strwrapper_t<nSize>
    {
        // message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
        // message : see usage of 'sInput'
        // error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
        constexpr auto foo = strwrapper_t<nSize>(sInput);

        return foo;
    }
};

int main()
{
    strwrapper::create("foo");

    return 0;
}
```

The constructor doesn't even do anything, but my compilation fails because of `sInput`'s usage. I'm unable to figure out the cause; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, so what's the issue? This compiles fine (not counting the unused constructor parameter).

Comment: Does it? This code doesn't seem to compile for me on Visual Studio 2019 (v142) with C++17. I get the compiler error "expression did not evaluate to a constant"

Comment: Yeah, this compiles in gcc9.3, but not on trunk.

Comment: @cigien As soon as you try to read from `sInput` in the constructor, it stops compiling even on GCC 9.3.

Comment: Removing `constexpr` from `foo` makes `create` work. But what's the point of wrapping the constructor in `create`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I plan to feed the constructor with an extra variable which will be used to manipulate the string at compile-time, and I rather have it inside the `create` function to avoid code duplication. Also, this allows me to "seamlessly" pass the size of the string to the template parameter `nSize`

Comment: Passing the size can done with a custom deduction guide.

Comment: However, seems like if I remove `constexpr` from `foo`, whatever I put inside the constructor won't be evaluated during compile time..